# Is there a way to run QAF BDD test on AWS device farm?

Tags: aws-device-farm, qaf

I'm trying to execute QAF BDD test using AWS device farm (Appium test using TestNG) but unfortunately it wont trigger the execution on testcase even there is no error. The same working fine while execute it locally.

The testng.xml configurations:

```
<suite name="QAF Demo" verbose="0">
    <test name="Launch_App" enabled="true">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="SMOKE"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

BDD file:

```
SCENARIO: SampleTest
META-DATA: {"description":"Sample Test Scenario","groups":["SMOKE"]}

    Given print message

END
```

The log from AWS :

> ```
> Start Appium TestNG test
> [DeviceFarm] java -Dappium.screenshots.dir=$DEVICEFARM_SCREENSHOT_PATH org.testng.TestNG -testjar *-tests.jar -d $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/test-output -verbose 10
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> [TestRunner] Running the tests in 'Launch_App' with parallel mode:false
> [RunInfo] Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@7cf10a6f priority: 10
> include groups [SMOKE]
>  exclude groups: [] Scanarios location:  
> [TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl class=com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory]
> [TestNG] Running:
>   /tmp/scratchE1xraV.scratch/test-packagel0A01c/testng.xml
>
> [SuiteRunner] Created 1 TestRunners
> [TestRunner] Running test Launch_App on 1  classes,  included groups:[SMOKE ] excluded groups:[]
> ===== Test class
> com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory
> ======
> [TestNG] RUNNING: Suite: "Launch_App" containing "0" Tests (config: /tmp/scratchE1xraV.scratch/test-packagel0A01c/testng.xml)
> ===== Invoked methods
> =====
> Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryz6SHdY/test-output/QAF Demo/Launch_App.html
> Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryz6SHdY/test-output/QAF Demo/Launch_App.xml
>
> ===============================================
>     Launch_App
>     Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
> ===============================================
>
> [TestNG] 
> [TestNG] ===============================================
> [TestNG]     Launch_App
> [TestNG]     Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
> [TestNG] ===============================================
>
> ===============================================
> QAF Demo
> Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
> ===============================================
> ```

Is it due to custom method selector used by QAF?

Comment: it looks that it didn't found any bdd file. Did you packaged resources and scenarios directory in zip? When extracted it need to be available in execution directory.

Comment: @user861594, I packaged in zip in same way as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html). additionally  i mentioned  `<testResources>
   <testResource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/config</directory>
   </testResource>
  </testResources>` in pom.xml so it can find testng.xml

Comment: Is there anything else i need to do to package resources and scenarios ?

Comment: Have you already tried running these tests with the [custom test environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html)? It seems more well-suited for running tests. If you think its something specific to AWS Device Farm, you can try posting the URL of the run where you are experiencing this issue on the AWS Device Farm [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193&start=0) for help from them.

Answer (score 3):

To integrate QAF with AWS Device Farm you can follow below steps.

1. As per AWS mentioned do required configuration in your project. Refer [working with Appium on AWS Device Farm Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-appium.html).
2. Add below folders in your assembly zip files. You can add these folders by updating your `assembly/zip.xml`.

```xml
<fileSet>
    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
    <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
      <include>/resources/</include>
      <include>/scenarios/</include>
      <include>/config/</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

3. Now build zip using `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true` command.
4. Follow the same reference link to upload your test package zip.
5. Provide path of testng xml in your configuration yml file.

```sh
java -Dappium.screenshots.dir=$DEVICEFARM_SCREENSHOT_PATH org.testng.TestNG "config/testrun_config.xml" -d $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/test-output -verbose 10
```

6. Move QAF Results to build artifacts folder to fetch QAF result.

```
post_test:
    commands:
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - cp -R test-results $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
      - cp -R img $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
      - cp -R img $DEVICEFARM_SCREENSHOT_PATH
```